# How Do I Temporarily Ignore Files in a Flutter App Build?

Tags: flutter

I'm migrating an app from [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) to [Riverpod](https://riverpod.dev), and I'd like to start at the top of my UI and work down. Is there a way to make my app ignore certain files so it will still compile while I work my way through my app?

For example, I'd like to start in `main.dart` and get that working with an empty `Container()` child, and then move down through my UI as I fix stuff.

But as it is now, I have to fix hundreds of build errors before I can even see anything.  In Xcode, I can uncheck a file to exclude it from the build. I'm looking for something similar.

Comment: You can move them all into an adjacent directory and disable the analyzer on them.